# Windows Random Text / Lorem Ipsum Generator

Tags: windows, gratis, automation

Is there a free Windows application that have a shortcut to insert random text to current focused textbox?

So the program runs in background, and whenever I press the shortcut e.g CTRL+ALT+R, the program then append random text / lorem ipsum to the textbox.

Preferably the word count is not static by preset number but dynamic, (can be random or some pop up appear asking how many word to generate, press enter, and then the textbox filled).

Will be much better if the shortcut is customizable.

Anyone knows?

Comment: I have a LoremIpsum.txt always available to copy text from it. Just an idea.

Answer (score -1):

You are referring to random password generator ? Then there is several password generators available just go with " **random password generator** " it's a good app

Comment: No, I'm not particularly looking for password generator, but lorem ipsum or random text that we can set the number of generated word. Will be using up to 200 words.
I don't think any password generator can generate up to 200 words.

Comment: I want to use lorem ipsum to inserting dummy text when developing software and websites, instead of mashing keyboard randomly.

Comment: Ok then.i may look for something else